# How to remove block from world?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I develop an annihilation ray in Minecraft Forge 1.6.4, that must completely remove blocks from world. Remove procedure is written like this:

```
worldObj.destroyBlock(position.intX(), position.intY(), position.intZ(), false);
```

It looks good, but sometimes "ghost blocks" appears, this blocks looks like air block, but if I will set any block on its place, old removed block instantly recreated!

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking for because your description doesn't match anything possibly imaginable. Do you perhaps have screenshots demonstrating this?

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping that line with this:

if (!this.worldObj.isRemote) {

}

This if statement checks to see if the current world is clientside or serverside.

I would try to help more but you didn't provide a lot of code to go off of.

Ghost blocks happen when the serverside and clientside both try to change the blocks at the same time. With this if statement it should only remove the blocks from the serverside and then the clientside will catch up instead of getting all confused.

I had the ghosting block problem when creating custom tnt and this solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome! If you don't mind making this the accepted answer, I'd greatly appreciate it. :)